# Kronecker notation of an operator

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra, terminology-and-notation

Suppose I have the state $|A\rangle=|x\rangle^l\otimes |y\rangle^l \otimes |z\rangle^l \otimes |0\rangle_x^l\otimes |0\rangle_y^l\otimes |0\rangle_z^l$. I perform the transformation between the $|x\rangle$ register and first $0_x$ register that is $$U|x,0\rangle\to |x,(2x)~\text{mod}~l\rangle$$
Suppose if $|x\rangle=|x_0x_1x_2...x_{l-1}\rangle$ and $|0\rangle=|0_00_1000..0_{l-1}\rangle$ then the result is $|x\rangle|x_1x_2x_3....x_{l-1}0\rangle$.
So the tensorial notation for this operator on state $A$ is
\begin{align}
U=\prod_{i=0}^{l-2}  \left( I^{\otimes 1+i}\otimes P_0\otimes I^{\otimes 3l-2}\otimes I\otimes I^{l-1-i}\otimes I^{\otimes 2l} \right.   \\\left.+I^{\otimes 1+i}\otimes P_1\otimes I^{\otimes 3l-2}\otimes X\otimes I^{l-1-i}\otimes I^{\otimes 2l}\right)
\end{align}
Is this operator correct for the operation that I want to perform?

Comment: Your function is not unitary, it wasn't supposed to be?